# How can I update multiple records and persist the changes using Hibernate Reactive w/ Panache and Mutiny

Tags: java, quarkus-panache, mutiny

I have an Example entity class that extends PanacheEntityBase. My goal is to get a stream or list of examples and then run updates on each one and persist those updates, then run another function that does some other stuff - I know this other function works and it takes in an id parameter and returns a `Uni<Void>`.

A very similar function is working that takes an id, then uses Example.findById(id) to update a single Example record. However, I cannot figure out how to get this working with multiple records.

Here is the code that *does* work for a single Example record, taking in the `id` as a parameter:

```
return Panache.withTransaction(() -> Example.<Example>findById(id)
    .onItem().ifNull().failWith(new NotFoundException("Example not found."))
    .onItem().transformToUni(example -> {
        example.setState("new state");
        example.setStateChangedAt(Instant.now());
        return example.<Example>persist();
    })
    .onItem().call(example -> anotherService.anotherFunction(example.getId()))
    .onItem().ignore()
    .andContinueWithNull()
);
```

So for multiple records, I am trying a similar thing (it should run on every Example record where state="old state").

Right now, after the `.transform(...).onItem()` it looks like it is working with a `Uni<Example>` where as in the above single-record code, at that point it is working with just an `Example` and I do not understand why.

```
return Panache.withTransaction(() -> Example.<Example>stream("state", "old state")
    .onItem().transform(example -> {
        example.setState("new state");
        example.setStateChangedAt(Instant.now());
        return example.<Example>persist();
    }).onItem().call(example -> {
        anotherService.anotherFunction(example.getId());
    })
    .onItem().ignore()
    .andContinueWithNull()
);
```

I have also looked into some options using `Example.list()` instead of `Example.stream()`, but I have been unable to get it working that why either. I have been struggling through all this Uni and Multi stuff and still do not have a super firm grasp on it. Please assist in getting that second update transaction working.

Comment: have you find a solution? I also having the same problem

Comment: I don't have access to this code anymore and cannot remember exactly what I did. I remember this example quarkus project helped: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-super-heroes/blob/main/rest-heroes/src/main/java/io/quarkus/sample/superheroes/hero/service/HeroService.java. For example the `deleteAllHeroes()` function performs another function on multiple records.

Comment: I just realise I'm not using reactive version of the panache, so that doesn't work for me. do you have an idea how to do it using non reactive version?